# Two sections on my website are being seen as one

Tags: html, css

My two section #wrapper and #stats are both being see as the wrapper by google dev tools. Now this is affecting my development as any changes to the css gets mangled within the two sections.

In google dev tools when i hover over the wrapper content, it shows the div as stats.
I have looked and looked but I cant find anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/responsive.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
<header class="main-header">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="html/about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="html/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="html/contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<span class="title">We offer garden building such as trellis and fencing, as     well as outdoor lighting, water features and much more</span>
<h1> Garden Construction</h1>
<img class="arrow" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="arrow down">
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>Our Services</h2>
<section>
<ul id="gallery">
<li>
<a href="img/trellisandfence.jpg">
<p>Trellis and Fencing</p>
<img src="img/trellisandfence.jpg">
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="img/light.jpg">
<p>Outdoor garden lighting</p>
<img src="img/light.jpg">
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="img/gravelretention.jpg">
<p>Gravel renetion system</p>
<img src="img/gravelretention.jpg">
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="img/gardenbuilding.jpg">
<p>Outdoor building such as sheds and cabins</p>
<img src="img/gardenbuilding.jpg">
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="img/waterfeature.jpg">
<p>Water features - any size, any style</p>
<img src="img/waterfeature.jpg">
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
<div id="stats">
<ul>
<li>
<h4>We can organise appointments at your convinence</h4>
<img src="img/appointments.png">            
</li>
<li>
<h4>We offer free consulations and quotes</h4>
<img src="img/consultation.png">            
</li>
<li>
<h4>We are fully licenced and qualifed with over 25 years experience.</h4>
<img src="img/licenced.png">            
</li>
<li>
<h4>We have looked untaken multi-million euro projects</h4>
<img src="img/euro.png">            
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Try using the `<section id="wrapper">` and `<section id="stats">` as your sections, instead of using DIVs. That's all sections are - specialized divs for SEO.